# Python Menu function not working properly

Tags: python

Good day, I'm having issues with this program I'm doing as a school assignment.  Basically, the Menu function displays as I want it but it will not properly execute any of the other functions.  So if I enter a number it just loops back to the menu. Even the exit option doesn't work. I really can't figure out why. It seems to follow the syntax of all my example code exactly.

```
def Menu():
    print ("")
    print ("CALCULATIONS MENU")
    print ("1) AREA (SQUARE)")
    print ("2) AREA (RECTANGLE)")
    print ("3) AREA (CIRCLE)")
    print ("4) PERIMETER (SQUARE)")
    print ("5) PERIMETER (RECTANGLE)")
    print ("6) PERIMETER (CIRCLE)")
    print ("7) EXIT")
    Test = input ("Input menu option(1-7): ")
    return Test

def ASQ(Height):
    print ("")
    print ("The area of the square is:", Height * Height)

def AREC(Height, Width):
    print ("")
    print ("The area of the rectangle is:", Height * Width)

def ACIR(Radius):
    print ("")
    print ("The area of the circle is:", 3.1415 * Radius**2)

def PSQ(Height):
    print ("")
    print ("The perimeter of the square is:", Height * 4)

def PREC(Height, Width):
    print ("")
    print ("The perimeter of the rectangle is:", Width*2 + Height*2)

def PCIR(Diameter):
    print ("")
    print ("The perimeter of the circle is:", Diameter * 3.1415)

Loop = 1
Selection = 0
while Loop == 1:
    Selection = Menu()
    if Selection == 1:
        ASQ(input("Enter the length of one side: "))
    elif Selection == 2:
        AREC(input("Enter height: "), input("Enter width: "))
    elif Selection == 3:
        ACIR(input("Enter radius: "))
    elif Selection == 4:
        PSQ(input("Enter the length of one side: "))
    elif Selection == 5:
        PREC(input("Enter height: "), input("Enter width: "))
    elif Selection == 6:
        PCIR(input("Enter diameter: "))
    elif Selection == 7:
        Loop = 0

print ("Good bye")
```

Comment: `Test = int(input ("Input menu option(1-7): "))` else `Test` is a string and doesn't compare to your integers.

Comment: Thanks.  It's odd that none of the example code they use define an int in similar cases.  It certainly helped.  Now there's new errors but I think I'm on the right path.

Comment: Python 2: would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
Test = input ("Input menu option(1-7): ")
```

`Test` will contain the user input as a `string`, so when you save the value of `Test` in `Selection` and compare it's value in `if-statements`,

```
if Selection == 1:
```

you are comparing `int` with a `string` which is not going to work.

**Solution:**

Either convert the user input to `int` by changing

```
Test = input("Input menu option(1-7): ")
```

to

```
Test = int(input ("Input menu option(1-7): "))
```

or
include the numbers in `if-statements` in double quotes `""` like

```
if Selection == "1":
```